# my localhost does not display the app.js in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern

Im having trouble rendering my app.js in localhost from my React App.

I was working on an old tutorial which had to make some changes and currently stuck on modifying my app.js and index.js to render in localhost,

in the console.log it won't show me any errors besides to edit my combine reducers, unless that's the problem.

I want to be able to see my app.js in localhost and not a white screen.

app.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {Container, AppBar, Typography, Grow, Grid} from '@material-ui/core';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import { getPosts } from './actions/posts';
import Posts from './components/Posts/Posts';
import Form from './components/Form/Form';
import memories from './images/memories.png';
import useStyles from './styles';

const App = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
}, [dispatch]);

return (
    <Container maxidth="lg">
        <AppBar className={classes.AppBar} color="inherit">
            <Typography className={classes.heading} variant="h2" align='center'>Memories</Typography>
            <img className={classes.image} src={memories} alt="memories" height="1460" />
            <h1>hello</h1>
            
        </AppBar>
        <Grow in>
            <Container>
                <Grid container justify="space-between" alignitems="stretch" spacing={3}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
                        <Posts />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                        <Form />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Container>
        </Grow>
    </Container>
    
);
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';

import App from './App';

const store = configureStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
  );
```

in reducers folder

index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import posts from './posts';

export default combineReducers({ posts });
```

posts.js

```
export default (posts = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_ALL':
            return action.payload;
        case 'CREATE':
            return posts;
            
        default:
            return posts;
    }
}
```

here is an image on my [console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmnvN.png)

Comment: What does the console in ur browser say?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @nnaem I added a screenshot.

Comment: youre not showing us the reducer file... Thats where the error is coming from...

Comment: try changing `configureStore({reducer:reducers}, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));`

Comment: @abhishekSharma I tried configureStore({reducer:reducers}, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));  and still nothing the tutorial had createStore instead of configureStore

Comment: @alexzoo why combining reducers when you just have one reducer?